# Understanding std::is_constructible

Tags: c++, type-traits

Wrt [std::is_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)

have the following questions based on the example provided:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
class Foo
{
    int v1;
    double v2;
public:
    Foo(int n) : v1(n), v2() {}
    Foo(int n, double f) noexcept : v1(n), v2(f) {}
};
 
int main()
{
    auto is = [](bool o) { return (o ? "\t" "is " : "\t" "isn't "); };
    std::cout << "Foo ...\n"
              << is(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Foo, const Foo&>)
              << "Trivially-constructible from const Foo&\n"
              << is(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Foo, int>)
              << "Trivially-constructible from int\n"
              << is(std::is_constructible_v<Foo, int>)
              << "Constructible from int\n"
              << is(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Foo, int>)
              << "Nothrow-constructible from int\n"
              << is(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Foo, int, double>)
              << "Nothrow-constructible from int and double\n";
}

Foo ...
        is Trivially-constructible from const Foo&
        isn't Trivially-constructible from int
        is Constructible from int
        isn't Nothrow-constructible from int
        is Nothrow-constructible from int and double
```

Based on the definition of `class Foo` in the example

i) `Foo` is considered trivially constructible from `const Foo&`, or in other words a copy constructor; is this due to the reason that the copy constructor is trivial as it would be generated by the compiler?

ii) `Foo` is not considered trivially constructible from the constructor `Foo(int)`, although the definition of the constructor sets the default value of the `double` member `v2` of the class to `0.0` as I understand from the construct `v2()`; What is the reasoning in this instance for `Foo` being not trivially constructible?

Appreciate your thoughts

TIA

Comment: Please make your question self contained. If the examples on cppreference change your question won't make any sense

Comment: @AlanBirtles Agree edited the question to paste the example here

Comment: @Vinod - If you have written a constructor, it is by definition not trivial. A compiler generated one *might* be trivial, if it in turn uses only trivial operations. Add a `std::string` member, and you will see triviality change.